# Are Azure Batch virtual machines automatically shut down after a job completes?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-batch

I was just curious about the lifecycle of the Azure Batch's virtual machines. Say a VM is created and a task is completed. Is the VM terminated after a successful completion?

Comment: Hey @Daath had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

•   No, according to the best practices official documentation and the nodes and pools documentation, the Azure VM in a batch doesn’t shutdown unless a repetitive job is initiated. If a repetitive scheduled job is to be executed on a VM in an Azure Batch, then the time period for which the batch job is to be executed is to be defined during the batch job creation itself and resource allocation instance.

Thus, ***when a batch job on an Azure VM is completed, the Azure VM becomes idle in state and after a defined threshold period, it is deleted***. The threshold period is the time for which the Azure VM in the node pool is in hibernation state/idle. ***Post completion of which and absence of any lined-up task or job, the Azure VM in the node pool gets deleted/deallocated if a spot instance is used.***

•   Please refer to the below official documentation link on the provisioning of pool and compute node lifetime: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/nodes-and-pools#pool-and-compute-node-lifetime